Chrome devtools freezes while open on my website after 5 seconds
This just started happening today. Nothing has changed on my work website since this started breaking but now if I open devtools about 5 seconds later the devtools will be completely unresponsive. Can't click on any tabs or console. Not really sure where to start to debug. Already restarted computer, uninstalled chrome.
I am on macosx Sonoma 14.5 and chrome 127.0.6533.89
Any ideas how to debug this one? Kind of impossible to work.
Update:
I quit out of chrome and deleted ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome and that seems to have fixed it

Sounds like a possible bug in Chrome, I'd suggest searching here: https://issues.chromium.org/issues

same here! my colleagues do not experience the same, and I am with M3 and they are not, might be related. only happens when running locally though.. weird!

same, I have it for the last month now. it happened mostly on breakpoints so I can't debug anymore in Chromium dev tools, it also happened in Arc. The solution of deleting the application support/chrome library didn't work for me.

I'm also experience complete freeze of Dev Tools in v127 whenever hitting a breakpoint. Could be this bug. Installing current beta 128 seems to have solved the issue for me (on first glance...).

Also facing same. I did a reset of devtools settings, still the issue exists. Looks like a bug.
